# Using webview AdblockWebView crashes

Tags: android, webview, adblock

I am trying to use AdblockWebView library to block ads on Android webview. I tried to connect with my phone but the developed app crashes. I am using the following code. Is there anything I should change.

**MainActivit.java**
    import org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.android.webview.AdblockWebView;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AdblockWebView superWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        superWebView = findViewById(R.id.main_webview);



        superWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        superWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        superWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        superWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        superWebView.clearCache(true);

        superWebView.loadUrl("https://m.youtube.com/");

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.android.webview.AdblockWebView
        android:id="@+id/main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**build.gradle (project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.webview"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:3.14'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you add the exception and its stacktrace to your question

Comment: @Jaime I am facing similar crashes when accessing https://pelisplushd.net/ stacktrace: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/YcVV6b8ss4/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely coming from superWebView.clearCache(true);

Remove this line and the app should run.